# POST 404 Error (Component not found) in Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I am running some custom php file that contains some javascript code within a Joomla website through an extension called sourcerer. Everything works as expected from the php side of things however I am experiencing an issue with a call to another php file made from within a javascript.  Here is the javascript code in question and on the second line is the "suburb.php" file that is called from within this code that is causing the issue.

```
$.ajax({
 url : 'suburb.php',
 dataType: "json", 
 method: 'post',
 data: {
     name_startsWith: request.term,
     type: 'suburb_table',
     row_num : 1
 },
 success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
         var code = item.split("|");
         return {
             label: code[0],
             value: code[0],
             data : item
         }
     }));
 }
});
```

The problem I am having is that even though the originating php file that contains this javascript is in the same directory as the suburb.php file, Joomla seems to change the URL call to "localhost/index.php/menu_alias/suburb.php" and this causes a POST error 404 (Component non found).

I have tried using many variation of the url path in that second line of the code, but all have failed. Can somebody tell me what my url path should look like for this to work?

Thank you,
Adri

Comment: The value of the field url is wrong. Please try an absolute url instead of an relative one. Where exactly is your file located in the file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. I tried with absolute urls with the standard format, but it gave some sort of restricted error. Somebody then suggested this option, which has worked and solved my problem

```
url : "<?php echo Juri::base(); ?>directory/etc/suburb.php",
```

Thanks, Adri

Comment: Hi Adri, could you please mark your answer as the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute URL instead of of just "suburb.php" so it should be something like: http://www.[joomlasite].com/suburb.php

As for the localhost, then I would say you likely have the `$live_site` set to "localhost" in your configuration.php - make sure you set the `$live_site` to empty. If that's not the case, then search your database for any occurrence of localhost.